# how to set a value using config files in entity when saving

Tags: java, spring

I'm using springmvc + hibernate to develop a website, here is the thing: I need to set a value to entity's column, this value can be set when I publish this website, so I put this value to application.properties, but how can i use it as a default value to the entity when I save this entity.

Answer (score 0):

lets say the field corresponding to your column is called `myColumn` and is of type `String`. Your field is part of entity class `myEntity`. In this case you can simply do this:

```
@Entity
public class myEntity{

  private String myColumn = "my_default_value";
  //other fields..
}
```

This will automatically set the column `myColumn` to "my_default_value" if you don't set it explicitly using a setter.

EDIT: I assumed here that you generate your tables from `@Entity` annotated classes, otherwise this will not work.

EDIT 2: here are all the ways to set a default value explained: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-default-column-values

also note that: If your field is of a numeric primitive type it will always be assigned a default value when saving to the database. integer fields like `int, long, double` etc will be assigned `0` by default. Furthermore `boolean` will be assigned `false` by default. If you don't want that, use a `wrapper class` instead. So `Integer` instead of int, `Long` instead of long. `Boolean` instead of boolean. The default value will always be `NULL` if you use a `wrapper class` as a datatype.

Comment: You can not use @Value annotation inside a POJO (hibernate or no hibernate)

Comment: ok thanks for the heads-up, didn't know that. I will remove that part then.

Comment: The value can be injected in a repository for example and from there into the entity. Still not very clean if the entity is used from another context.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, because I will use this value in many entities, So I need to put this value in application.properties, and I want to set this value to entities, any ideas? thanks

Comment: @Tong like Alexander Petrov said, you can inject the value in the `JpaRepository` corresponding to your Entity class. All you have to do next is to override the `save()` method.

Comment: ok,seems I have to rewrite the JpaRepository class, thanks for all your help

Comment: When I write NewJpaRepository, I got another problem, In this class, I can't get the value when I use'@Value("${}"), SomeOne knows why？

Comment: @Tong try adding this annotation `@PropertySources(value = {@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")})
` to any class annotated with `@Configuration`

Comment: I already add @PropertySources in my Application.java, The main class, It's not working.  Did I make something wrong, any ideas?

Comment: I already add PropertySources in my Application.java, The main class, It's not working.  Did I make something wrong, any ideas?

Comment: is your application.properties in the `resources` map?

Comment: yes， and I have five properties files in my resouces folder, no matter what file I put my value in , I can't get the value in my custom newSimpleJpaRepository, the other file with controller or service can get the value correctly, wired thing